# Oracle subquery internal error

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

The query in listing 1 joins two subqueries, both of which are computed from two named subqueries (ANIMAL and SEA_CREATURE). The output should list animals that don't live in the sea, and list animals that do live in the sea.

When run in a console window (SQL Navigator 5.5), the server returns error:

```
15:21:30  ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [evapls1], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
```

**Why?** And how to get around it?

Interesting to note, I can run the same query in a program written in Delphi XE7 (using TSQLQuery component), and it works ok. But this is not a problem with SQL Navigator. If I create a view containing the expression in listing 1, selecting from the view does not output an error. The problem is in the oracle server.

If I make the ANIMAL subquery really simple, like in Listing 2, it works. but anything else, even just selecting from a table, results in this internal error.

Listing 1: (Outputs error)

```
with ANIMAL as (
  select ANIMAL_NAME
    from xmltable( 't/e' passing xmltype( '<t><e>Tuna</e><e>Cat</e><e>Dolphin</e><e>Swallow</e></t>')
                  columns
                    ANIMAL_NAME varchar2(100) path 'text()')),

SEA_CREATURE as (
  select           'Tuna' as CREATURE_NAME from dual
  union all select 'Shark'    from dual
  union all select 'Dolphin'  from dual
  union all select 'Plankton' from dual)

select NONSEA_ANIMALS, SEA_ANIMALS
  from (

  select stringagg( ANIMAL_NAME) as NONSEA_ANIMALS
    from (      (select * from ANIMAL)
          minus (select CREATURE_NAME as ANIMAL_NAME from SEA_CREATURE))),

  (select stringagg( ANIMAL_NAME) as SEA_ANIMALS
    from ANIMAL
    where ANIMAL_NAME in
      (select CREATURE_NAME as ANIMAL_NAME from SEA_CREATURE))
```

Listing 2: (This works)

```
with ANIMAL as (
  select           'Tuna' as ANIMAL_NAME from dual
  union all select 'Cat'     from dual
  union all select 'Dolphin' from dual
  union all select 'Swallow' from dual),

SEA_CREATURE as (
  select           'Tuna' as CREATURE_NAME from dual
  union all select 'Shark'    from dual
  union all select 'Dolphin'  from dual
  union all select 'Plankton' from dual)

select NONSEA_ANIMALS, SEA_ANIMALS
  from (

  select stringagg( ANIMAL_NAME) as NONSEA_ANIMALS
    from (      (select * from ANIMAL)
          minus (select CREATURE_NAME as ANIMAL_NAME from SEA_CREATURE))),

  (select stringagg( ANIMAL_NAME) as SEA_ANIMALS
    from ANIMAL
    where ANIMAL_NAME in
      (select CREATURE_NAME as ANIMAL_NAME from SEA_CREATURE));
```

Listing 3: Expected output for expressions in both Listings 1 & 2:

```
NONSEA_ANIMALS    SEA_ANIMALS
-------------------------------
'Cat,Swallow'    'Tuna,Dolphin'
```

The Oracle banner is shown in Listing 4.

Listing 4: select * from v$version

```
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bi
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
CORE    10.2.0.4.0  Production
TNS for IBM/AIX RISC System/6000: Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Productio
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
```

How is this craziness explained?

---

## Update

Here is the explain plan ...

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                            | Name                        |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                     |                             |
|   1 |  TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION           |                             |
|   2 |   LOAD AS SELECT                     |                             |
|   3 |    VIEW                              |                             |
|   4 |     COLLECTION ITERATOR PICKLER FETCH| XMLSEQUENCEFROMXMLTYPE      |
|   5 |   LOAD AS SELECT                     |                             |
|   6 |    UNION-ALL                         |                             |
|   7 |     FAST DUAL                        |                             |
|   8 |     FAST DUAL                        |                             |
|   9 |     FAST DUAL                        |                             |
|  10 |     FAST DUAL                        |                             |
|  11 |   NESTED LOOPS                       |                             |
|  12 |    VIEW                              |                             |
|  13 |     SORT AGGREGATE                   |                             |
|  14 |      VIEW                            |                             |
|  15 |       MINUS                          |                             |
|  16 |        SORT UNIQUE                   |                             |
|  17 |         VIEW                         |                             |
|  18 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL           | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6666_765BCCBD |
|  19 |        SORT UNIQUE                   |                             |
|  20 |         VIEW                         |                             |
|  21 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL           | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6667_765BCCBD |
|  22 |    VIEW                              |                             |
|  23 |     SORT AGGREGATE                   |                             |
|  24 |      HASH JOIN RIGHT SEMI            |                             |
|  25 |       VIEW                           | VW_NSO_1                    |
|  26 |        VIEW                          |                             |
|  27 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL            | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6667_765BCCBD |
|  28 |       VIEW                           |                             |
|  29 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL             | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6666_765BCCBD |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you share the [Execution Plan](http://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/dbms_xplan.php#display) of your first query?

Comment: What's the stringagg function?

Comment: stringagg() takes all the rows and returns a comma-separated value as one row. You could just replace it with min() or max() and it is much the same problem.

Comment: I tried and I got the weirdest error ever: ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar Updated to show explain plan.

Comment: @pablomatico ORA-03113 means your connection timed out. You need to close your session, restart it, and try again.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin I know what it means but my connection get closed every time I run the query. Sorry I can't help, my DB must be misconfigured

Answer (score 0):

`ORA-03113` and `ORA-6000` usually happens on using `WITH` clause query when
something fatal happened on execution.

Oracle's *subquery factoring* or `WITH` clause, can be overused at times. Oracle may create a global temporary table for every query inside WITH clause, for reusing the results. So, `XMLTABLE()` here, could have created another `GTT` here, and perhaps this crash the database.

> `COLLECTION ITERATOR PICKLER FETCH` is something when fetched from a
>   PL/SL object. [It returns pickled(packed and formatted) data](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:498034700346999115)
>
> It might involve creation of some temp table beneath like I mentioned previously. So the subquery factoring and the PL/Sql array selection didnt go well.

I have also seen queries with *nested* `UNION ALL` in `WITH` getting crashed.

This is most a bug in Oracle, and should be reported to them.

Only way to get around this now, would be reforming the query. In our application, usage of `WITH` is strictly restricted(due to high CPU usage) for report only purposes executed as batch.